# Why is there a line in the middle of the Planck full sky map?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, cosmic-microwave-background, milky-way

Why there is a straight line (or perhaps a flat surface) in the middle of the Planck full sky map?

[image: Planck-FSM]
<sub>(source: [esa.int](http://sci.esa.int/science-e-media/img/e5/PLANCK_FSM_03_all_views.gif))</sub>

and zoom

[image: Zoom surface collision of big bang]
<sub>(source: [handshakemag.com](http://handshakemag.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/PLANCK_FSM_03_Black.jpg))</sub>

(it makes it seem that the big bang was a collision between two unknown surfaces)

Comment: It's a major task to remove this 'galactic sirrus' so that the actual main scientific target can be studied in detail.  It's not called 'background' for no reason ;-)

Comment: It is a flat surface indeed!

Answer (score 12):

What you're seeing is the galactic plane of the Milky Way. There are several processes emitting at a variety of wavelengths, and because the emission is so nearby it comes out quite bright on the all sky map. Planck observes at about $\mathrm{mm}$ wavelengths, so the most prominent emission within the galaxy is thermal emission from dust clouds.

Often maps are "cleaned" by coming up with a model for the galactic emission and subtracting it, leaving approximately only extragalactic emission. Alternately if data in the galactic plane is unobserved, the missing region may be fit according to an appropriate model (using the observed region as a boundary condition) and filled in.

Comment: For more images of the galactic plane of Milky Way in different wavelengths, see [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/114516/25301) of mine.